# Cloning HDD to SSD and using a HDD for Data Storage

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, clonezilla, rhel-6

First time poster with a possibly unique situation:

I've been tapped by my company to setup several new computers with RHEL 6.4. These new machines have a 250gb SSD and a 3TB hdd, and previously came with a windows 7 image that was removed The computers were purchased without regard as to their compatibility with Linux, and an image was created independent of the new hardware as well. The image was cloned to a portable USB drive via Clonezilla and then handed to me. I was able to move the cloned image to the SSD, but that brings me to my questions:

1) Once the SSD is cloned with the RHEL 6.4 image, how do I configure the computer to use the hdd for storage (/home, etc.) and the ssd as a boot drive? The image is already pre-set and cloned, so steps that I can take within RHEL 6 without having to install from scratch would be appreciated.

2) After the SSD+HDD are configured properly, how do I optimize their functionality? I've seen some SSD optimization guides for other distro's and I didn't know if it would readly apply to RHEL 6.

/etc/fstab currently looks like this:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root / ext4 defaults 11 
UUID-7ab6cb62-ba60-4600-b6db-cbfe10b68135 /boot ext4 defaults 12 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home /home ext4 defaults 11 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap swap swap defaults 00 
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 00 
devptts /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 00 
sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 00 
proc /proc proc defaults 00
```

Comment: What's `/etc/fstab` currently contain?

Comment: @ernie
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root/ ext4 defaults 11  UUID-7ab6cb62-ba60-4600-b6db-cbfe10b68135 /boot ext4 defaults 12  /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home /home ex4 defaults 11  /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap swap swap defaults 00  tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults 00 devptts /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 00  sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 00 proc /proc proc defaults 00  
EDIT: tried to add linebreaks, didn't work.

Comment: As per @ernie - to sort out (1), you simply need to add the references to /home on the hdd device in fstab and then mount -a (or reboot).  Of-course, you first need to configure and format the hdd device with the appropriate filesystem.  You want to make sure that the hdd partition does not have the bootable flag set, and the sdd is set to boot first in BIOS.

Comment: @user301634 generally edit your question to provide extra information if you can as that makes it easier for everyone to find.  I don't know enough about RHEL and the /dev/mapper they use, but if you don't mind just using UUIDs, the general stepps would be to format the SSD, get it's UUID, unmount the existing /home, and edit the fstab to replace the old home with your new device . . . you could remount the old home to a different mount point and copy it over as well if you wanted.

Comment: @ernie Thank you very much, both for the steps as well as the edits. Currently, I only see the UUID belonging to the SSD and not the HDD that I'm attempting to move the /home directory to. Could you provide me with the steps to perhaps retrieve the HDD UUID? And does the mount/unmount simply require a mount -a?

Comment: Both those questions are easily googled.  You can get the UUID with a command of the form `blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/sda1`.  `mount -a`  just mounts everything in the fstab.  You'll want to google for umount and mounting individual drives.

Comment: @ernie I did, and I now have the /home on the proper partition on the HDD as well as the swap. My last couple of questions refer to a few things I read in my previous search: a) should I alter the "swapiness" to help with optimization? and b) what should I add to the entries in the fstab to engage TRIM, and is that even necessary for use with an SSD in RHEL 6.4?

Comment: I'm not sure about the SSD parameters in RHEL, so I can't help you there.  If you got this all working, it'd be nice to answer your own question here, and document the steps you took for others who might find this question . . .

Comment: Sorry, completely new and didn't know the protocols. Will do so.

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the desired image to the SSD and installing the platter HDD, perform the following steps:

1. Partition the HDD. You'll want a partition for the swap and a partition for the /home, but if you also want to move temp directories and the like to HDD, setup partitions for those as well. 2gb is a fair size for the swap partition, apportion the other partitions as you like, but save the bulk for /home as that is where most of your files will be stored.
2. Open the /etc/fstab with your favorite editor, and change the UUID associated with /home from it's LV_Volume or SSD partition location to the one associated with your /home partition on the HDD. Do the same if you setup any other partitions for your temp directory(ies), and so on. If you do not have the UUID of the HDD, execute the **blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/sda1** command to get the UUID, replacing the **sda1** portion with the location of your respective partitions.
3. Execute the **mount -a** command. This will mount the redesignated drives in the fstab file.
4. Reboot. The new partitions should be mounted, but double-check by verifying UUIDs and proper partition size.